# Permissions messed up in home folder

Tags: 16.04, permissions, chmod, chown

Despite the fact that I didn't run any `chmod` or `chown` commands, I seemed to have lost the ability to `cd` into some folders in my home directory.
So I ran according to various answers on this forum since I have no clue about linux permissions:

```
sudo chmod -R 666 /home/rasmus/
sudo chown -c rasmus /home/rasmus/
sudo chown rasmus:rasmus /home/rasmus/
chmod 750 /home/rasmus/
sudo chown -R rasmus:rasmus /home/rasmus/
sudo chmod a+rx /home
sudo chmod u+w /home
```

leaving my home dir in this state:

```
10:57:35: 8D:[~] ls -l
total 52
drw-rw-rw- 2 rasmus rasmus 4096 Apr 15 10:43 catkin_ws/
drw-rw-rw- 2 rasmus rasmus 4096 Apr 14 16:31 Desktop/
drw-rw-rw- 3 rasmus rasmus 4096 Apr 15 09:31 Documents/
drw-rw-rw- 4 rasmus rasmus 4096 Apr 14 14:55 dotfiles/
drw-rw-rw- 3 rasmus rasmus 4096 Apr 14 15:27 Downloads/
-rw-rw-rw- 1 rasmus rasmus 8980 Apr 14 14:03 examples.desktop
drw-rw-rw- 2 rasmus rasmus 4096 Apr 14 16:31 Music/
drw-rw-rw- 2 rasmus rasmus 4096 Apr 14 16:31 Pictures/
drw-rw-rw- 2 rasmus rasmus 4096 Apr 14 16:31 Public/
drw-rw-rw- 2 rasmus rasmus 4096 Apr 14 16:31 Templates/
drw-rw-rw- 2 rasmus rasmus 4096 Apr 14 14:22 Videos/
```

Apparently, I can read the folders, but not `cd` into them:

```
10:58:54: 8D:[~] ls Desktop/
10:58:58: 8D:[~] cd Desktop/
bash: cd: Desktop/: Permission denied
```

What do I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know where the command

```
sudo chmod -R 666 /home/rasmus/
```

is from. But that one pretty bad. It removes the executable bit on all folderes which is needed to list a directory or change to that directory. Furthermore, you gave read/write access on each file in your home directory to anyone. You maybe also want to fix that.

Since all your files and directories have *666* access rights, you could restore the directory setting as follows.

```
sudo find /home/rasmus -type d -exec chmod 755 "{}" \;
```